# When is $\frac{2 n f(n)}{n !}$ in the order of some fixed power of $n$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, exponential-function, computational-complexity, factorial

I would like to know when $\frac{2 n f(n)}{n !}$ is $O (n^b)$ where $b$ is a constant. Here, $n$ is a positive integer.

My attempt:

$$
\frac{2 n f(n)}{n !}
= \frac{2 n f(n)}{\sqrt{2 \pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n}\\
= \sqrt{2 n} \pi^{\frac{-1}{2}}   e^n n^{-n}f(n)\\
= \sqrt{2} \pi^{\frac{-1}{2}} e^n n^{\frac{1}{2} - n}     f(n)
$$

So, it becomes $O (n^b)$ when $f(n) = e^{-n} n^{n-\frac{1}{2}} n^b = O(n^n)$

Am I getting it right?